# How to create an associative array using a 2 dimentional array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

How can i create an associative array using the array below, In the **fastest and shortest** way.

```
$list = array(array('name', 'aram'), array('family', 'alipoor'));
```

Something like:

```
$list = array('name' => 'aram', 'family' => 'alipoor');
```

Comment: Is is safe to assume that you're not running into any speed issues anyway? And additionally: How do you measure fastest and shortest? Isn't the fastest always the shortest? Or is shortest the number of characters the code consists of?

Comment: In my situation fastest means fastest to write (characters) and speed is not that important.

Comment: Keep in mind that code is far more often read than written, so if you're open for a suggestion, you should more take care that code is easy (fast) to read, not fast to type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortest I can think of:

```
$newlist = array();
foreach ( $list as $keyval ) {
    $newlist[ $keyval[0] ] = $keyval[1];
}
```

Comment: It will be shortest if there wasn't any loops. Isn't there any way to do it in one single line using php functions

Comment: Is the initial array of defined length? Otherwise you have to have a loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
$assocArray = array();

foreach($list as $subArray)
{
    $assocArray[$subArray[0]] = $subArray[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Terrible approach, but

```
$lst = array_combine(array_map('array_shift',$list), array_map('array_pop',$list));
```

Works **only** for two-element inner arrays.

Note: **three** implicit loops in this solution. So better use approach from Rijk van Wel or kevinmajor1 answer

Answer (score 0):

I generally think foreach is pretty well readable and normally pretty fast. If you want it in one line, you can do with foreach as well:

```
$nl = array(); foreach($list as $k=>$v) $nl[$k]=$v; $list = $nl; unset($nl);
```

Which is basically demonstrating that there is no value in getting something "single line".

Or if you prefer callbacks for some reason I don't know of:

```
$list = array_reduce($list, function($v,$w) {return $v+array($w[0]=>$w[1]);}, array());
```

Which demonstrates that as well. It will hardly be faster than foreach, in any case, the speed differences most certainly do not matter in your case.